# Saving a spinner position to a text file

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to save the selected location of my spinner in a text file when I click the save button.

Currently this is what I have. The spinner works fine but when I try to add the part to save the spinner position (saveSettings) this is where my problems lie.

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error:(56, 85) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to File

Error:(61, 40) error: method getPosition in class ArrayAdapter<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: CharSequence
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class ArrayAdapter

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I think the problem is that I tried to combine 2 different approaches but as i'm still learning i'm confusing myself as to the correct method for saving a selected spinner position.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    String SelectedServer;

    /**
    * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.serverUrl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                SelectedServer = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }


        });
    }

    public void saveSettings(View view) {

        File txtFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFolder/");
        if (!txtFolder.exists()) {
            txtFolder.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(txtFolder, "setting.txt");
        String.valueOf(SelectedServer.getBytes());
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(SelectedServer.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Setting Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

So I am looking for help in fixing this problem.
Any advice?

Comment: but what is your question ?

Comment: Maybe just bragging with the code that works... :D

Comment: Sorry i have edited. its late and i'm sleepy @Vucko i wish it was working :D

Comment: @Dooves Ah I'm just messing with ya :) Tried to help, look @ the answer.

Comment: @Vucko Thanks a lot that fixed the first error. I think i have managed to redo my code so that the second error is fixed. Only issue now is that, although the app runs, I am getting the following error in my logcat
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/setting.txt: open failed: ENOENT (no such file or directory)

i have updated my code above to show the changes. Anyone know why i'm not able to create the folder even if it doesn't exist. I though i'd checked initially that if i doesn't then make it. Thanks

Comment: No problem, mate. Well having fixed your original problem, I'd suggest you accept the answer. As for the second issue, try to google how to make a folder if it does not exist, you should find plenty solutions online.

Comment: Sorry, i was actually being a bit special. I was testing on sdk 23 so that requires further permissions in the .java file not just the manifest. So after testing everything above works fine now. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the first error:

```
File txtFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFolder/";
```

You are assigning the `string` value to the File. You might wanna put that value in the constructor `new File(String path)`:

```
File txtFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFolder/");
```

The second error is this:

```
String SelectedServer = adapter.getPosition().toString();
```

I would use `String.valueOf(adapter.getPosition());` or implicit conversion `""+adapter.getPosition();`.

If that's not the case, then you need to check what `getPosition` returns (maybe it's empty).